# Row Level Security in Postgres on Normalized Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

### The premise

[In documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html), Row Level Security seems great. Based on what I've read I can now stop creating views like this:

```
SELECT data.*
FROM data
JOIN user_data
ON data.id = user_data.data_id
AND user_data.role = CURRENT_ROLE
```

The great part is, Postgres has a great analysis for that `view` starting with an index scan then a hash join on the `user_data` table, exactly what we want to happen because it's crazy fast. Compare that with a my RLS implementation:

```
CREATE POLICY data_owner
ON data
FOR ALL
TO user
USING (
  (
    SELECT TRUE AS BOOL FROM (
      SELECT data_id FROM user_data WHERE user_role = CURRENT_USER
    ) AS user_data WHERE user_data.data_id = data.id
  ) = true
)
WITH CHECK (TRUE);
```

This bummer of a policy executes the condition for *each row* in the `data` table, instead of optimizing by scoping the query to the rows which our `CURRENT_USER` has access to, like our view does. To be clear, that means `select * from data` hits **every** row in the `data` table.

### The question

How do I write a policy with an inner `select` which doesn't test said `select` on **every** row in the target table. Said another way: how do I get RLS to run my policy on the target table *before* running the actual query on the result?

p.s. I've left this question someone vague and fiddle-less, mostly because [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) hasn't hit 9.5 yet. Let me know if I need to add more color or some gists to get my question across.

Comment: I stopped using SQLFiddle because it essentially never works for me. For Postgres I use: http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL may be able to generate a better plan if you phrase the policy like this:

```
...
USING (EXISTS
          (SELECT data_id
           FROM user_data
           WHERE user_data.data_id = data.id
             AND role = current_user
          )
      )
```

You should have a (`PRIMARY KEY`?) index `ON user_data (role, data_id)` to speed up nested loop joins.

But I think that it would be a better design to include the permission information in the `data` table itself, perhaps using the `name[]` type:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   val text,
   acl name[] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES (1, 'one',   ARRAY[name 'laurenz', name 'advpg']);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (2, 'two',   ARRAY[name 'advpg']);
INSERT INTO data VALUES (3, 'three', ARRAY[name 'laurenz']);
```

Then you can use a policy like this:

```
CREATE POLICY data_owner ON data FOR ALL TO PUBLIC
   USING (acl @> ARRAY[current_user::name])
   WITH CHECK (TRUE);
ALTER TABLE data ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE data FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

When I `SELECT`, I get only the rows for which I have permission:

```
SELECT id, val FROM data;
 id |  val
----+-------
  1 | one
  3 | three
(2 rows)
```

You can define a GIN index to support that condition:

```
CREATE INDEX ON data USING gin (acl _name_ops);
```

Comment: Is it appropriate to use `name[]` here? The Postgres docs indicate that designers should not use `name[]`, as it is only for system catalogues. From the docs: "There are two other fixed-length character types in PostgreSQL, shown in Table 8-5. The name type exists only for the storage of identifiers in the internal system catalogs and is not intended for use by the general user." Link here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: `name` should be fine, as only PostgreSQL identifiers are stored. But it is just as well to use `text`.